# Programmatically packing 2TB of various sized files into folders of 25GB? (I used python, any language will be acceptable)

Tags: python, file, sorting, backup, packing

I have around 4,000 files of wildly different sizes that I am trying to back up as efficiently as is reasonably possible. I know compressing them all into a giant tarball and splitting evenly is a solution, but as I am using Bluray discs, if I scratch one section, I risk losing the whole disc's contents.

I wrote a python script to put all the files (coupled with their sizes) into an array. I take the biggest file first, and either add the next biggest (if that total is still less than 25GB) or move down the list until there is one I can add that will, until I hit the size limit, then start over with the next biggest remaining file.

This works reasonably well, but it gets really ragged at the end and I will end up using 15 more discs than is mathematically theoretically required.

Anyone have a better method I'm not aware of? (This seems like a Google coding interview question lol). I don't need it to be perfect, I just want to make sure I'm not doing this stupidly before I run through this giant stack of non-cheap BD-Rs. I've included by code for reference.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
import os
import sys

# Max size per disc
pmax = 25000000000

# Walk dir
walkdir = os.path.realpath(sys.argv[1])
flist = []
for root, directories, filenames in os.walk( walkdir ):
    for filename in filenames:
        f = os.path.join(root,filename)
        fsize = os.path.getsize(f)
        flist.append((fsize,f))
flist.sort()
flist.reverse()

running_total = 0
running_list = []
groups = []

while flist :
    for pair in flist :
        if running_total + pair[0] < pmax :
            running_list.append(pair[1])
            running_total = running_total + pair[0]
            flist.remove(pair)
    groups.append(l)
    running_list = []
    running_total = 0
print('This will take {} discs.'.format(len(groups)))
```

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bin_packing_problem

Comment: Those formulas just made my eyes bleed.According to this I am currently implementing the "first-fit" strategy.

Comment: If I may ask, if those formulas made your eyes bleed, how did you find what was the "mathematically theoretically required" amount? As the page linked by @SLaks says, it is an NP-hard problem, you can't just do 4000 files by eye... if you mean the sum divided by a disk space, you might well be having already the optimal answer with your heuristic algorithm. Anyway, you should look online for already implemented good heuristics, it's a non-trivial research subject that won't fit a stackoverflow answer, see e.g. http://www.martinbroadhurst.com/bin-packing.html

Comment: Share the list of sizes?

Comment: I just brute forced it by going down the list, adding smaller and smaller files until I was out of files or the disk filled up, then repeat. By "mathematically required" I just meant size of all files / 25GB = ideal # of discs. I can post the resulting arrays on pastebin if you are still interested.

Comment: It's 80,000 too many characters long for a comment, but the raw sizes and the solution the above code generated is here: https://pastebin.com/7QNZWqEX The first few discs add up to almost exactly 25GB, but it degenerates from there and the last few are garbage, but I don't know a better way to do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just brute forced it by going down the list, adding smaller and smaller files until I was out of files or the disk filled up, then repeat. By "mathematically required" I just meant size of all files / 25GB = ideal # of discs. I can post the resulting arrays on